# How to disable vcl styles on external dll forms in delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, vcl-styles

I have an issue in Delphi 10.1 Berlin using VCL Styles and an external DLL.

I'm using a Nitgen DLL to enroll fingerprints in my application.  The process is handled by a COM object in `NBSPCOM.dll`.

When I call the method to enroll, the form from the DLL appears odd.  It shows the Form background, images and controls are wrong, etc.

If I compile the application in XE8, the problem vanishes and all works fine.

I can't find the class of the DLL forms to try a VCL Styles hook.

Some screenshots of the form:

Original form

[image]

Wrong Form

[image]

Comment: *They that sow the wind, shall reap the whirlwind*

Comment: The native winapi controls (Static, Button, RebarWindow32, ...) are styled using a WH_CBT Hook, So maybe the issue is related to this area.  Try disabling the styling of these controls using the  `Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.SystemHooks` property like so  `TStyleManager.SystemHooks := [];`

Comment: @RRUZ, man you save my life :D . I put the code TStyleManager.SystemHooks := []; in OnCreate of the Form and Work. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you uses the `VCL Styles` the native winapi controls (Static, Button, RebarWindow32, ...) are styled using a [`WH_CBT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_cbthook) Hook, My guess is which the dll is using a `static` or `Button` winapi control where the background of the image is drawn. To overcome this you can disable the styling of these controls using the `Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.SystemHooks` property like so

```
TStyleManager.SystemHooks := [];
```